# Error: The method can not be called because the receiver can be null

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to save the form on a button click but it is giving me an error that the "method can not be called because the receiver can be null". I'm providing a null check but the error is not getting solved. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here is the code**

```
onPressed: () {
    if (_formKey.currentState != null) {
        _formKey.currentState.save(); // this gives the error
    }
},
```

This onPressed is linked with the elevated button and the _formKey here is this:

```
// key to work with the form
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are checking that `currentState` is not null you can use the `!` to fix your problem.

```
onPressed: () {
    if (_formKey.currentState != null) {
        _formKey.currentState!.save();
    }
},
```

Another way to fix this is to create a variable which stores the `currentState`.

```
onPressed: () {
    final state = _formKey.currentState;
    if (state != null) {
        state.save();
    }
},
```